# Failed to open tcp:8080 port on Google Cloud

Tags: curl, tcp, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

[Google Cloud Firewall Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xS74a.jpg)

My current custom firewall rules for google cloud looks like above. I want to open port 8080 to send curl request to google compute engine instance.

The command I will be using to get a response from compute engine is -

`(echo -n '{"data": "'; base64 cat.0.jpg; echo '"}') | curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @- http://Compute-Engine-Static-IP-Address:8080`

However, I got the error `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 214.137.154.104.bc.googleusercontent.com port 8080: Connection refused` when I send the above command using command prompt in windows.

I had also scanned with nmap and found that 8080 port is closed.

[Scan report from nmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUKJh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Is there another firewall rule with a higher priority that's blocking it? Also, can you make sure that the instance is actually listening on 8080? Is there a process running that's serving something on that port?